# Adding animations to static HTML page navigation

Tags: ajax, html, animation

Is there a simple way to add animations to static HTML page navigations? 
My client didn't want any animations initially, so I used static HTML pages on the site I'm building, now, the site being almost finished he changed his mind. I only need a simple fade effect to one specific div when using page navigation. (link tags)

If he had told me before that he wants animations on the site, I would have used ajax as always, adding the fade effect like this (using jQuery):

```
$(target).fadeout();
$(target).load(url, function() {
    $(this).fadein();
});
```

I really don't feel like rewriting the whole site to use ajax, and my client doesn't feel like either to pay a surplus because of this.

Comment: what effect is it you need? what should it do?

Comment: a simple fade effect to one specific div. Fade out when a navigation link is clicked, load the new page, then fade in.

Comment: a new div that opens? fades to black? fades to transparency? change colors? can you be more specific?

Comment: No. The site has a few static HTML pages, basically the same content on all pages, only the container div changes its content. When a user clicks on a link, I'd like to add a fadeOut effect to the div, wait for the new page to load, the fade it in. I know how to do this, but it is really complicated, lots of code, so that's why I'm asking if there's a simple way to do it.

Comment: Is it really a big deal to write a common script, and load that script to the top of each page? `<script src="mydivfade.js">`.  If the div always has the same class or id, it should magically work once you write the script once.  Am I missing something?